# Reading progress on a Kindle Paperwhite

Tags: kindle

I like to know how much time I've got left in any book I'm reading on my Kindle. I set it up each time a start reading but it seems to default to location or no reading progress at all. I know it's easy to put it back to show what I want but it's frustrating! Why won't it just stay on the setting I want?
Any suggestions would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Once you open any book in your kindle notebook. you need to go Aa > More > Reading Progress and Apply Time left in the chapter and **click on Save current settings**.